# Multiple sibling folders for apex classes when deploying with ant?

Tags: deployment, ant, ant-script

How would I set up my build file so I can split up apex classes into sibling folders inside `src`?

Currently, I got `deployRoot = "src"` set up in the build file, and I assumed that ANT can recognize all `.cls` files, wherever they reside (as long as they are in the `src` directory), but apparently it only recognizes files inside the `classes` folder. How can I make ANT understand that there is an additional folder with apex classes inside the `helperclasses` folder?

```
src
├── classes
│   ├── apexclass1.cls
│   └── apexclass2.cls
├── helperclasses
│   ├── testfactorydefault1class.cls
│   └── testfactorydefaul2class.cls
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported in Ant. You're looking for sfdx. If you want to do this in Ant, you can provide multiple packages.

```
C:\WORKSPACE\DEMO\SRC
├───package1
│   │   package.xml
│   │
│   └───classes
│           Class1.cls
│           Class1.cls-meta.xml
│
└───package2
    │   package.xml
    │
    └───classes
            Class2.cls
            Class2.cls-meta.xml
```

If you do this, make sure you don't use the "single package" flag.

The package.xml file is a full manifest file for all the content of that folder. Given the above example, the files would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
        <members>Class1</members>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
        <members>Class2</members>
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

For each respective package folder.

Comment: Thanks - what goes in each `package.xml` file in `pkg1` and `pkg2`? Should there be one `package.xml` in each subdirectory *as well* as in the parent directory?

Also, not exactly sure where ant/sfdx overlaps. Does SFDX replace a tool like Travis, or can travis be set up to deploy with sfdx as well?

Comment: @erikvm each package.xml contains a full manifest file that lists every component contained in the package. You should already have one of these to start from.

Comment: @erikvm I was previously mobile, now that I'm home, I updated the answer so it's hopefully clearer.

Comment: @erikvm Also you could [convert source format to metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_convert) and deploy using Metadata API (Ant)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @sfdcfox. What about the `package.xml` file that sits in the parent directory of "src" - should that "parent" package xml still exist? And if so, should it have `<types>....</types>` with everything **but** apex classes from the subfolders?
The "parent" package.xml I'm referring to is the one automatically generated that provides this:
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>

etc

Comment: @erikvm in multipackage mode, the parent folder (`src`) should not contain any files, only folders. There's no package.xml in the src folder, as listed in this answer.

Comment: Hmm, we have it set up like this: https://imgur.com/a/6lK4tIc

The package.xml sits in the src folder - just not sure where all this metadata information should be stored, and if we can keep that package.xml file where it is right now? (ignore the sfdx files and all that - we're still using ant - I'm just using sfdx myself for testing purposes right now)

Comment: @erikvm If you're going with the multiple package model described here, that package.xml you have will need to be moved to each package folder, and will no longer live at it's current location. I uploaded a [zip file](https://paste.c-net.org/GalaxiesParticle) for you. Let me know if you get it. Note that sfdx's mdapi:deploy doesn't seem to like multiple package model, so you need to zip it first. The ZIP I linked won't work, either; you have to go in to the src folder, select both folders, and compress those in to a ZIP. Ant should work fine, though.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - I'm still not sure what I do with all the remaining stuff in the package.xml file.  What about LightningComponentBundle, AuraDefinitionBundle, ApexTrigger and all the other types that sits in the "default" package.xml. Do I need to create an individual package.xml and put them inside each folder as well? (granted they are in the default directory)?

And in your zip file - all the folders are still called "classes" - is that mandatory? What if I want the folder to be called "helperclasses", or "utilities"?

Comment: @erikvm You need exactly one package.xml per package folder, and it must be at the root of that folder, as demonstrated in the zip. Aside from the package.xml file, no other files are allowed in the root. To add different component types, you need to know the folder name for that type and the format of the content for that folder. These names come directly from the [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm); they tell the API what's inside, so you can't change them.

Comment: @erikvm You also cannot organize these folders in any way in the mdapi model. The structure is strictly: `package/type/name` or `package/type/name/parts`, which is determined by the metadata type. For example, LWC uses `package/lwc/componentName/componentFile` (.js, .html, .css, etc), while Apex classes all live in `package/classes`.